# Can Java infer type arguments from type parameter bounds?

Tags: java, generics

The following test program is derived from a more complicated program that does something useful. It compiles successfully with the Eclipse compiler.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InferenceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final List<Class<? extends Foo<?, ?>>> classes =
            new ArrayList<Class<? extends Foo<?, ?>>>();
        classes.add(Bar.class);
        System.out.println(makeOne(classes));
    }

    private static Foo<?, ?> makeOne(Iterable<Class<? extends Foo<?, ?>>> classes)
    {
        for (final Class<? extends Foo<?, ?>> cls : classes)
        {
            final Foo<?, ?> foo = make(cls); // javac error here
            if (foo != null)
                return foo;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // helper used to capture wildcards as type variables
    private static <A, B, C extends Foo<A, B>> Foo<A, B> make(Class<C> cls)
    {
        // assume that a real program actually references A and B
        try
        {
            return cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static interface Foo<A, B> {}

    public static class Bar implements Foo<Integer, Long> {}
}
```

However, with the Oracle JDK 1.7 javac, it fails with this:

```
InferenceTest.java:18: error: invalid inferred types for A,B; inferred type does not
 conform to declared bound(s)
            final Foo<?, ?> foo = make(cls);
                                      ^
    inferred: CAP#1
    bound(s): Foo<CAP#2,CAP#3>
  where A,B,C are type-variables:
    A extends Object declared in method <A,B,C>make(Class<C>)
    B extends Object declared in method <A,B,C>make(Class<C>)
    C extends Foo<A,B> declared in method <A,B,C>make(Class<C>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Foo<?,?> from capture of ? extends Foo<?,?>
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#3 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

Which compiler is right?

One suspicious aspect of the output above is `CAP#1 extends Foo<?,?>`. I would expect the type variable bounds to be `CAP#1 extends Foo<CAP#2,CAP#3>`. If this were the case, then the inferred bound of `CAP#1` would conform to the declared bounds. However, this might be a red herring, because C should indeed be inferred to be `CAP#1`, but the error message is regarding A and B.

---

Note that if I replace line 26 with the following, both compilers accept the program:

```
private static <C extends Foo<?, ?>> Foo<?, ?> make(Class<C> cls)
```

However, now I can't reference the captured types of the `Foo` parameters.

**Update:** Similarly accepted by both compilers (but also useless) is this:

```
private static <A, B, C extends Foo<? extends A, ? extends B>>
    Foo<? extends A, ? extends B> make(Class<C> cls)
```

It essentially causes `A` and `B` to be trivially inferred as `Object`, and therefore obviously not useful in any context. It does, however, lend credence to my theory below that `javac` will only perform inference on wildcard bounds, not capture bounds. If no one has any better ideas, this might be the (unfortunate) answer. **(End Update)**

---

I realize this whole question is likely TL;DR, but I'll continue in case someone else is hitting this issue...

Based on JLS 7, [§15.12.2.7 Inferring Type Arguments Based on Actual Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7), I've done the following analysis:

> Given a constraint of the form `A << F`, `A = F`, or `A >> F`:

Initially, we have one constraint of the form `A << F`, which indicates that type `A` is convertible to type `F` by method invocation conversion ([§5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)). Here, `A` is `Class<CAP#1 extends Foo<CAP#2, CAP#3>>` and `F` is `Class<C extends Foo<A, B>>`. Note that the other constraint forms (`A = F` and `A >> F`) only arise as the inference algorithm recurses.

Next, `C` should be inferred to be `CAP#1` by the following rules:

> (2.) Otherwise, if the constraint has the form `A << F`:
>
> - If `F` has the form `G<..., Yk-1, U, Yk+1, ...>`,
>     where `U` is a type expression that involves `Tj`,
>     then if `A` has a supertype of the form `G<..., Xk-1, V, Xk+1, ...>`
>     where `V` is a type expression,
>     this algorithm is applied recursively to the constraint `V = U`.

Here, `G` is `Class`, `U` and `Tj` are `C`, and `V` is `CAP#1`. Recursive application to `CAP#1 = C` should result in the constraint `C = CAP#1`:

> (3.) Otherwise, if the constraint has the form `A = F`:
>
> - If `F = Tj`, then the constraint `Tj = A` is implied.

Up to this point, the analysis seems to agree with the javac output. Perhaps the point of divergence is whether to continue attempting to infer `A` and `B`. For example, given this rule

> - If `F` has the form `G<..., Yk-1, ? extends U, Yk+1, ...>`,
>     where `U` involves `Tj`, then if `A` has a supertype that is one of:
>
>   - `G<..., Xk-1, V, Xk+1, ...>`, where `V` is a type expression.
>   - `G<..., Xk-1, ? extends V, Xk+1, ...>`.
>
> Then this algorithm is applied recursively to the constraint `V << U`.

If `CAP#1` is considered to be a wildcard (which it *is* a capture of), then this rule applies, and inference continues recursively with `U` as `Foo<A, B>` and `V` as `Foo<CAP#2, CAP#3>`. As above, this would yield `A = CAP#2` and `B = CAP#3`.

However, if `CAP#1` is simply a type variable, then none of the rules seem to consider its bounds. Perhaps this concession at the end of the section in the spec refers to such cases:

> The type inference algorithm should be viewed as a heuristic, designed to perform well in practice. If it fails to infer the desired result, explicit type parameters may be used instead.

Obviously, wildcards cannot be used as explicit type parameters. :-(

Comment: What version of `javac` are you using? `javac -version`

Comment: @Jeffrey: More specifically than 1.7? `javac 1.7.0_25`

Comment: @BevynQ: Yes, that example "workaround" was in my question. However, it's not useful, since the point of `make` is to capture the wildcards, e.g. for representing multiple instances of the same type in further method calls or creating other object instances with those type parameters. The issue has nothing to do with the assignability of the result to `Foo<?,?>`; that part works in either compiler.

Comment: Woo! This definitely isn't `TL;DR`. Thanks for pointing this out! +1

Comment: FWIW, IntelliJ also successfully compiles your example.

Comment: This question may be useful for analysis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935185

Comment: @cambec intellij 12.1.4 javac 1.7_21 does not.

Comment: @BevynQ: Thanks for trying to help out. I was just clarifying that a) the workaround you mention was in the original question verbatim, so I don't understand what info it adds, and b) the compiler error is in the method invocation, not that it's refusing to assign the result. If you remove all mention of `foo` (i.e. no result variable, no assignment, no `if`, no `return`), the error still occurs.

Comment: @BevynQ: To clarify, IntelliJ _IDE_ reports no error (same behavior as Eclipse), but an error occurs when IntelliJ invokes javac during a project build. I'm also using 12.1.4 and 1.7.0_21.

Comment: Tested this on javac 1.8.0-ea-b96 and got a compile error there as well. The error message is _huge_: `java: method make in class InferenceTest cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.Class<C> found: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends InferenceTest.Foo<?,?>> reason: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s) inferred: capture#2 of ? equality constraints(s): capture#2 of ?,capture#3 of ?,capture#4 of ?,capture#5 of ?,...`. This continues on and on until `capture#201`. Certainly looks like a bug. (And Java 8 is supposed to have an improved type inferencing algo).

Comment: @cambecc: Thanks for the link. It didn't give me much insight into this problem, but researching this problem made it easy to answer that one. ;-) Using the technique that answers that question is actually how I ended up at this one. Out of the frying pan and into the fire...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you start from the following inference constraint:

`class<#1>, #1 <: Foo<?, ?>`

Which gives you a solution for C, namely C = #1.

Then you need to check whether C conforms to declared bounds - the bound of C is Foo, so you end up with this check:

`#1 <: Foo<A,B>`

which can be rewritten as

`Bound(#1) <: Foo<A, B>`

hence:

`Foo<?, ?> <: Foo<A, B>`

Now, here the compiler does a capture conversion of the LHS (here's where #2 and #3 are generated):

`Foo<#2, #3> <: Foo<A, B>`

Which means

`A = #2`

`B = #3`

So, we have that our solution is { A = #2, B = #3, C = #1 }.

Is that a valid solution? In order to answer that question we need to check whether the inferred types are compatible with the inference variable bounds, after type substitution, so:

`[A:=#2]A <: Object`
`#2 <: Object - ok`

`[B:=#3]B <: Object`
`#3 <: Object - ok`

`[C:=#1]C <: [A:=#2, B:=#3]Foo<A, B>`
`#1 <: Foo<#2, #3>`
`Foo<?, ?> <: Foo<#2, #3>`
`Foo<#4, #5> <: Foo<#2, #3> - not ok`

Hence the error.

The spec is underspecified when it comes to the interplay between inference and captured types, so it's quite normal (but not good!) to have different behaviors when switching between different compilers. However some of these issues are being worked on, both from a compiler perspective and from a JLS perspective, so issues like this should get fixed in the medium term.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Why does `Foo<?, ?>` get reintroduced with a new capture? If the compiler performs a separate capture conversion in the checking phase from the inference phase, it seems you can never have satisfiable (non-trivial) inference constraints with wildcards. IOW, #2 and #4 correspond to the same wildcard, yet `#4 <: #2` will never be true. The JLS doesn't seem to require this (in fact, no mention of capture in that section at all), and it breaks sensible code with no workaround, so it's a javac bug, right?

Comment: It's a spec bug - the spec is mandating the new capture in the first place; my opinion is that, depending on how the post-inference check is executed, certain compiler might be affected by this behavior. Javac certainly is.

But what you say is 100% spot on: generating captured variables during subtyping as part of the inference process leads to unsatisfiable constraints - which is why the spec is being reworked in this area.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear. Do you know if the spec work is targeting Java 8, 9, or beyond? For now, I just used a raw cast as a workaround, since I have confidence from Eclipse that the logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I've noticed:

1. `CAP#1` is not a wildcard, it is a type variable because of [capture conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).
2. On the first step, the JLS mentions that `U` is the type *expression* while `Tj` is the type *parameter*. The JLS does not explicitly define what a type *expression* is, but my gut feeling is that it includes the bounds of the type parameter. If that is the case, `U` would be `C extends Foo<A,B>` and `V` would be `CAP#1 extends Foo<CAP#2, CAP#3>`. Following the type inference algorithm:

`V = U` -> `C = CAP#1` AND `Foo<CAP#2, CAP#3> = Foo<A, B>`

You can continue to apply the type inference algorithm to the above, and you will end up with `A= CAP#2` and `B=CAP#3`.

I believe you have spotted a bug with Oracle's compiler

Comment: Agreed, `CAP#n` is a type variable that is introduced due to capture conversion of a wildcard. What I was getting at there was whether capture conversion happens entirely before type inference. It took a while to find it, but the answer appears to be yes: "If the expression name appears in a context where it is subject to [...] method invocation conversion [...], then the type of the expression name is the declared type of the field, local variable, or parameter after capture conversion. [§6.5.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1)

Comment: @Trevor Yay! Was looking for this point also (5 years later).